# Non-associative, non-commutative binary operation with a identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations, associativity

Can you give me few examples of binary operation that it is not associative, not commutative but has an identity element?

Comment: Does it have to be both a left- and right- identity?

Comment: Vafa, maybe you should hand in your assignment before you post it here.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: If I have posted one question from the assignment here, it does not mean that I am going to copy verbatim solutions from here into my solution of the assignment. In fact, as you will see in my solution, I have given a different example. I posted the question here because I was interested to see other binary operations that I could not think of. Next if I ever wanted to copy solutions from here into my solution manual, I would not be that stupid to ask the question with my real name and identity. (if this is ever what you meant.)

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, so if e is your identity and a is an element of your binary operation, then you should get $ae=ea=a$.

Comment: @Vafa Khalighi: If there is an identity in a associative, commutative groupoid, then it must be both left and right, but a left identity in an nonassociative noncommutative groupoid is not guaranteed to be a right identity. Thats why I asked (also, in all the excellent examples given by Jacob Schlater, the identity is only one sided).

Comment: @Mitch: You might be right. I do not know much about group theory to comment on this. This is Gerry Myerson's question for us. And I believe by identity he means that it is both right and left identity.

Comment: Vafa, I have read the comment you wrote to me. I can't answer there, so I'll answer here. **FIRST**, hand in your assignment; **THEN**, post questions from it online. Better: wait until all your classmates have handed in their assignments before you post assignment questions to a public website. I'm sure if you think about it, you'll see that this is the only sensible way to go about it. 

If your curiosity must be satisfied and you can't wait until everyone else has handed the assignment in, then come ask me f

Comment: What do you want me to do now? delete this? close this?

Comment: No, just be sure to credit anything you've seen here on this and other questions when you get your assignment in, and in the future, please do as I've suggested.

Comment: No problem. I will not post any more question of any assignment before its due date.

Answer (score 16):

Here are a couple easy examples, I'll leave it to you to verify their properties.

The natural numbers where $n\ast m=n^m$.

The integers where $n\ast m=n-m$.

The real numbers without zero where $x \ast y = \frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: $n*m=n^m$ has no identity element. call your identity, $I$, then $n^I=n$ gives $I=1$ but $I^n=n$ gives $I=n^\frac{1}{n}$, if $n=2$, then this $I$ is no longer a natural number (in fact, for ecah $n$, you get a different $I$) and since Identity element should be unique, your identity element does not exist.

Comment: With $n*m=n-m$, from $n-I=n$, you get $I=0$ but with $I-n=n$, you get $I=2n$ and so the identity does not exist.

Comment: Similarly with $x*y=\frac{x}{y}$, if $\frac{I}{x}=x$, you get $I=x^2$ but if $\frac{x}{I}=x$, then you get $I=1$. Hence identity does not exist.

Comment: That's a good point, I was just thinking in terms of left and right identities.

Comment: No, that was a great help. Thank you.

Comment: So this answer has 14 upvotes although all three examples are wrong? There is no identity.

Answer (score 12):

Pick any non-associative, non-commutative operation $\star$ on a set $X$. Now pick a new element $1$ which is *not* in $X$, let $Y=X\cup\{1\}$, and define a new operation $\bullet$ on $Y$ extending $\star$ and such that $$1\bullet x=x\bullet1=x$$ for all $x\in X$, and $1\bullet1=1$.

Comment: Is this one example, or many?  I'm not sure...

Comment: How can you possibly be not sure? It is *obviously* a family of examples, parametrized by the pair $(X,\star)$.

Comment: I was teasing.  I agree it is a family of examples, but that is one family.

Comment: I already knew this. but thanks anyway

Comment: I apologise for my comment. I now get what you meant by extending $*$!

Comment: Follow-up question: prove the family of examples given here is non-empty.

Answer (score 12):

The previous examples are all perfectly good, of course, but I thought I would add a rather low-brow way to see that such examples must be easy to generate.

Let $S$ be a finite set, and let's label its elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.  To define a binary operation $\star: S \times S \rightarrow S$ is equivalent to filling in all the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix $M = \{m_{ij} \}$ with elements of $S$.  In particular, since we have $n^2$ entries to fill out and $n$ possible choices for each entry, the total number of such matrices -- i.e., the total number of binary operations on $S$ -- is $n^{n^2}$.  This is a pretty big number even when $n$ is rather small.

Suppose we wish to enforce that the first element $x_1$ is a two-sided identity for our operation $\star$.  Then what we need is that for all $i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, 
$m_{1j} = x_j$ and $m_{i1} = x_i$.  In other words, the first row and first column of 
the matrix are entirely determined, but this leaves us with $n^2 - 2n + 1 = (n-1)^2$ entries left to choose.

It is clear that the operation is commutative iff the matrix is symmetric, i.e., $m_{ij} = m_{ji}$ for all $i,j$.  It is easy to give a precise count of the number 
of symmetric matrices with first row and first column as determined above and even easier to see that, as long as $n \geq 3$, most such matrices are not of this form.

Finally we come to associativity.  This is harder to see directly from the matrix, but it is easy to see that we have an awful lot of choices that will result in non-associative operations.  For instance, let us say for the sake of argument that 
$x_2 \star x_3 = x_4$ and $x_3 \star x_4 = x_5$ (all elements distinct): up to relabelling the elements, this is in some sense the generic situation.  Then we find

$(x_2 \star x_3) \star x_4) = x_4 \star x_4$

whereas

$x_2 \star (x_3 \star x_4) = x_2 \star x_5$.

Now for a randomly defined binary operation, the chance that these two products are 
equal is only $\frac{1}{n}$.  In any case, we can certainly define them to have different values even among $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ and get a nonassociative binary operation.

If you like counting things, it is a fun exercise to see what you can prove about **how many** of the $n^{(n-1)^2}$ binary operations on $S$ having $x_1$ as an identity 
are commutative, or associative, or both, or neither.  If $X_n$ is the number of 
such operations (having $x_1$ as an identity) which are neither commutative nor associative, it should be easy to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{n^{(n-1)^2}} = 1$, i.e., that "with probability $1$" a randomly chosen such operation is neither commutative nor associative.  I have no doubt that such results appear in the literature, with explicit bounds.  If someone knows a nice argument leading to an asymptotic or exact formula for $X_n$, I would be interested to see it.

Comment: This is an interesting question that I like to spend some time to think about it; but after finishing my assignments. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Nice answer. It is somewhat more difficult to enumerate matrices that encode non-associative operations. But you don't need that to find the limit. Note that X_n of non-commutative and non-associative matrices contains Y_n, the non-commutative matrices. And for every commutative matrix, we have half a matrix of free variables, or n^(n-2 choose 2) non-commutative matrices. So indeed as n grows large we find that the likelihood of getting a non-commutative matrix grows like 1 - 1/(n-2 choose 2) ~ 1 - n^(-2)

Answer (score 9):

the octonions!  more generally (multiplication in) further algebras coming from the [cayley-dickson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) construction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of an abelian group without associativity, inspired by an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622348/non-associative-commutative-binary-operation?noredirect=1&lq=1). Consider the game of rock-paper-scissors: $R$ is rock, $P$ is paper, $S$ is scissors, and $1$ is fold/draw/indeterminate. Let $\ast$ be the binary operation "play".

\begin{array}{r|cccc}
\ast & 1 & R & P & S\\
\hline
   1& 1 & R & P & S \\
   R & R& 1 & P & R\\
   P & P& P & 1 & S\\
   S & S& R & S & 1 .
\end{array}

The mutliplication table above defines a set of elements, with a binary operation, that is commutative and non-associative. Also, each element has an inverse (itself), and the identity exists.

Answer (score 2):

Since the assignment is over, I can send my solution. This is an example:
$$
x*y=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if }y=0;\\
|x|+y&\text{if }y\not=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An example of non-associative and non-commutative groupoid with identity is any non-commutative [**loop**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(algebra)) and, in particular, [this one](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles12/12_9_1_1.html), finite, of order $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a set $S=\{e,\alpha,\beta\}$ with three elements, and define multiplication on $S$ so that $e$ is the identity. To force the multiplication to be non-commutative, ensure that $\alpha\beta\neq\beta\alpha$. To ensure that is non-associative, define $\alpha\alpha=\beta$, so that $a\beta=\alpha(\alpha\alpha)$, and $\beta\alpha=(\alpha\alpha)\alpha$, and hence $(\alpha\alpha)\alpha\neq\alpha(\alpha\alpha)$.